# how to write unit test for fs.readdir

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I want to ask how to write unit test for this function. I've tried to mock it with mock-fs with keep getting the `undefined` for the result. Sorry I'm new to JavaSCript.

```
async getAllSongs(): String[] {
  const songs = await readdir(this.storageDirectory);
  return songs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like your function is part of an object/class but since I am not 100%, i will use a contrived example.

Lets assume that in my sample.js file, I have some code like so:

```js
//sample.js

const fs = require("fs").promises;

async function getAllSongs() {
  const songs = await fs.readdir(".");
  return songs;
}

module.exports = { getAllSongs };
```

To mock fs.readdir, you can use `jest.mock` and replace it with a function which return a promise since thats essentially what fs.readdir does.

```js
//sample.test.js

const fs = require("fs").promises;
const { getAllSongs } = require("./sample.js");

fs.readdir = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(["lol.js", "lmao.js", "wow.txt"]));

test("tests stuff", async () => {
  const result = await getAllSongs();
  expect(result).toEqual(["lol.js", "lmao.js", "wow.txt"]);
});
```

Because i stubbed out `fs.readdir` with a fake function from jest, when `getAllSongs` is executed, jest will use my fake function instead of the original implementation.